# JavaScript Not Working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I'm currently styling my username/password inputs on a webpage. They are working as intended in Firefox/Safari, but Internet Explorer throws the following error:

Line: 7, Char: 2, Objected required

It happens when I give focus to my inputs. This function is called onfocus:

```
function InputFocused(InputID)
{
    var InputObject = document.getElementById(InputID);
    DefaultValue = InputObject.value;
    InputObject.value = "";
    InputObject.style.color = "#000";
}
```

And this is the markup:

```
<input type="text" class="login" id="username" value="USERNAME" onfocus="InputFocused(this.id)" onblur="InputBlurred(this.id)" />
```

I thought this was pretty straightforward, but I have extremely little experience with JavaScript, so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to wire `onfocus` to this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your best bet would be to do this

```
   function InputFocused(DOM_OBJECT)
    {
        DefaultValue = DOM_OBJECT.value;
        DOM_OBJECT.value = "";
        DOM_OBJECT.style.color = "#000";
    }
```

While your HTML would look like this:

```
<input type="text" class="login" "id="username" value="USERNAME" onfocus="InputFocused(this)" onblur="InputBlurred(this)" />
```

This will pass the complete DOM object, rather than just passing the id.

I hope this helps!

Comment: While it does help make the code more concise, it doesn't solve the problem I'm having. Thanks for the tip though, I have implemented the suggestion.

Comment: It did, in fact, fix the IE problem, I just forgot to clear cache before checking the page again. Thanks. Any idea why passing this.id would throw the error, but passing the object reference was no issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why.  I've played with your code and have both versions working.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add a sanity check by `alert`ing the value of `InputID`.  There's a problem with your html (`"id=` instead of `id=`) but that might just be the result of a quick copy/paste.

Also: I notice that you're passing in the value of the id attribute and then looking up the element instead of just passing a reference to the element directly.

Comment: The first point was in fact just my pasting error. And I am now passing reference instead of ID, I see how it makes things more concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
<input type="text" class="login" "id="username" value="USERNAME" onfocus="InputFocused(this.id)" onblur="InputBlurred(this.id)" />
```

would need to be this

```
<input type="text" class="login" id="username" value="USERNAME" onfocus="InputFocused('username')" onblur="InputBlurred('username')" />
```

for the example given.

Comment: I was under the impression that both were exactly the same. Are they not? Besides the misplaced ".

Comment: Misplaced quotes can cause significant screw-ups. Always use a validator.

Comment: The misplaced quote wasn't in my actual code, just in the snippet I pasted here. My question was regarding this versus 'username'.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using?

The problem, I expect, is that when you're specifying onfocus="InputFocused(this.id)" I'm not sure IE knows what it's current context is and as a guess I'd say its because the DOM has not finished being built.

By way of a solution and explanation you can acheieve what you are trying to do like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="login" id="username" value="USERNAME"/>
```

Then in your javascript you can specify and set your event handlers:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
       //get the element...
    var txtUsrNm =  document.getElementById('username');

    //specify the event handler for focus
    txtUsrNm.onfocus = function(){
      this.value = "";
      this.style.color = "#000";
    }

//specify the event handler for blur
    txtUsrNm.onblur = function(){
      this.style.color = "#f00";
    }
```

I've left out your DefaultValue bit as I wasn't fully aware of what you were trying to do with it.
I haven't tested the code so sorry if it's not working. you can improve it all by wrapping in a function etc but thats probably a bit off topic.

Comment: I'm using IE7, and am now passing a reference to the object into my JS function instead of just ID, so it shouldn't be a context issue.